# Why can't i access /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet on my chromebook?

Tags: chrome-book

I am trying to disable the power button on my Chromebook but it keeps saying that the file is not available. What do I do?

Comment: ChromeOS doesn't use X11.

Comment: Thank you for that.